# Add SignalR client functionality to a Fable.Elmish application

Tags: signalr.client, fable-f#, elmish

I found 2 resources from the community

1.[Fable.SignalR](https://github.com/Shmew/Fable.SignalR) - A functional type-safe wrapper for SignalR and Fable. I am using Elmish so the package is [Fable.SignalR.Elmish](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fable.SignalR.Elmish/)

2.[fable-signalr](https://github.com/Prolucid/fable-import-signalr) - Fable bindings for SignalR

2 Is declared to work only before Fable 3, which is not my case.

With 1 I have a problem: I do not control the server side. The server application is a standard C# ASP.NET core Web Api application that uses SignalR.
All the examples I found for 1 require a shared F# library, which cannot be done in this case.

Let's suppose to have a simple Hub like in the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-signalr-hub):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub {}
}
```

and an Api controller that receives the hub context through DI and simply broadcasts a message:

```
class YatpApiController(IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext) : ControllerBase() {
   [HttpPost("signalr-broadcast")]
   public SignalrBroadcast()
   {
       hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Method1", "Message1");
   }
}
```

Can someone please

- Show how to use Fable.SignalR.Elmish client side with this very simple case?
- Give advise on an alternative way to connect to this simple hub from a Fable.Elmish application, without writing bindings to the javascript signalr package?